# Widgets and Graphs disappear in Datastax Opscenter‎ when I refresh browser

Tags: cassandra, datastax, opscenter

I installed Datastax Opscenter‎ and everything seemed fine initially.

After some time all Widgets and Graphs disappeared from the Dashboard. 
I can added them, but each time I refresh the browser they all disappear and Dashboard is empty.

Anyone face similar issue?

Comment: Sounds like you have a corrupted preset. What version of OpsC are you running?

Comment: Can you try running http://<HOST>:8888/<CLUSTER NAME>/rc/dashboard_presets/

and post the output.

Comment: {"message": "Resource not found.", "type": "NoSuchResource", "brief": "error"}

Comment: I was running 5.2.1 and upgraded to 5.2.2 yesterday. The problem is still were. Some corruption is likely as we had the disk where commit logs stored be filled to 100% and after that I had couple of commit logs partially written on one member. I had to remove these commit logs in order to start  Cassandra and then I ran noted repair operation.

Comment: Anyone know how to fix it without removing OpsCenter and re-installing it from scratch?

Comment: Hm, are you sure you got the cluster name right? The message should be different.  http://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/5.2/api/docs/ui.html?highlight=preset#method-get-dashboard-preset

Comment: We should be able to fix it without re-installing.

Comment: OK, I tried again, and I got this result now: {"6b2e0d68-dbd1-40e0-874a-a3703a452d88": {}}

Comment: The difference between first request and second request is "/" at the end of URL. First time I didn't put "/" at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if you ever figured it out, but you were halfway there. Deleting the broken preset will allow you to create a new one.
Step 1 (As mentioned in comments on question):

curl http://:8888//rc/dashboard_presets/

This will return an id string for the preset in a {"id"{}} format.

Step 2: curl -X "DELETE" http://:8888//rc/dashboard_presets/id  to remove the broken preset.

Note: A symptom of having to delete the preset is if the Default tab disappears from above the date selector.

Comment: Brilliant! Now I got it fixed by running DELETE request.